# Azure architecture to reliably import large amount of XML files to an Azure SQL table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am looking for architectural elements and guidelines to import large amount of XML files into an SQL Azure table.

Below are the characteristics of the XML file format and input:

- The xml files are not large.
- The schema of XML files is very simple and well defined.
- There are large number of XML files are being
  copied into a blob storage every 
  hour.

I was hoping to use Azure Stream Analytics with BLOB storage input as a perfect solution. However, Azure Stream Analytics does not support XML format :(

I am very well aware of SSIS option; however, SSIS is an IaaS and I am looking for Azure based PaaS option.

What are my Azure PaaS architecture options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just write it directly to SQL DB? 
The XML data type capability in SQL DB should be adequate for doing the parsing. This provides some example code: http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/parse-xml-with-sql-server/

If you don't control upstream of the Blob store than you've got a few options for tracking changes and pumping the data to SQL DB. Easiest is probably just a WebJob bound to the Blob: This should get you started: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/BlobOperations
There is still a bit of latency in the

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is that you use Azure Data Factory to perform data transformations prior to ingestion by Stream Analytic, although Data Factory will happily send the data directly into a SQL Table too.

There is a good blog post [Solving the “big legacy data” problem using Azure Data Factory…](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shwetasblogs/2015/05/06/solving-the-big-legacy-data-problem-using-azure-data-factory/) that explains it all.

Comment: Thank you @Michael What is the trigger mechanism in ADF? I need to process the XML files as soon they are uploaded to a BLOB. SA nicely scans the blob storage, take the new XML files and process them. Can ADF similarly monitor a blob for new files ?